# Updating Cache Struct via Mutable Reference

Tags: rust

I have this simple struct called `Path`:

```
struct Path {
    path_string: String,
    path_vec: Option<Vec<String>>,
}
```

The `String` is a path where each piece is separated by `"/"` and the vector representation is simply a list of the pieces. I wanted to be able to be able to cache the vector field on the first time it is accessed hence the `Option` wrapper.

I have the following function to access the vector:

```
    fn as_vec<'path>(&'path mut self) -> &'path Vec<String> {
        if self.path_vec.is_none() {
            let xs: Vec<String> = self.path_string.split("/").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
            self.path_vec = Some(xs);
        }

        match &self.path_vec {
            Some(xs) => xs,
            None => panic!("The impossible happened!"),
        }
    }
```

Is there a nicer way to structure this function that avoids the `panic`?

I originally tried to write something like this:

```
    fn as_vec<'path>(&'path mut self) -> &'path Vec<String> {
        match &self.path_vec {
            Some(xs) => xs,
            None => {
                let xs: Vec<String> = self.path_string.split("/").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
                self.path_vec = Some(xs);
                self.as_vec()
            }
        }
    }
```

But the `self.path_vec = Some(xs);` doesn't work because it isn't possible to update the struct when it's borrowed in the match.

Updating the match to use a mutable reference also doesn't work because it's not possible to have more than one mutable reference at a time.

Is this something that can be worked around or am I just stuck with the `panic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Option::get_or_insert_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with):

```rust
fn as_vec<'path>(&'path mut self) -> &'path Vec<String> {
    self.path_vec
        .get_or_insert_with(|| self.path_string.split("/").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect())
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, unfortunately this doesn't work because `self` is immutably borrowed inside the closure. Thanks for pointing out the `get_or_insert_with` function, using that I was able to create a version that works.

Comment: @JamesBurton This works in the 2021 edition, because it can borrow disjoint fields in closures. Make sure you're not using an older version.

Comment: Ah perfect, I will update my Rust version and give it a go!